# TeamCity Nuget update private package only

Tags: tfs, nuget, teamcity, nuget-package, nuget-server

We have a .net solution with around 30 projects in it.
We have a dependency on another internal project ( not in the same solution ), for which we use TeamCity NuGet to get the latest packages.

Currently, We update all packages using `nuget update-packages` command with a specific version that we need and check-in our code and then TeamCity builds it. 
(We commit packages too)

We are looking for a simpler solution where TeamCity can automatically update to the latest package and check-in into TFS.

I have tried using TeamCity NuGet installer but it didn't work, also, what I want is to get updates only for a specific package (not all the packages in projects).

I want to execute my NuGet update-packages command as a TeamCity build step so that it will update the packages and we don't have to do it manually every time we have a new update available.

Answer (score 0):

i think best option is you can use ms build.
msbuild will allow you to publish or push the nuget package along with version to server or will do checkin to tfs which is change.

Thanks
DJM